# How to get XPath of a list element generated by AJAX?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, java, xpath

When I type a keyword ("Documents 1.xml")

```
driver.findElement(By.id("documentSelect_enter")).sendKeys("Documents 1.xml");
```

in this field:

```
<input id="documentSelect_enter" type="text" style="width: 300px" /> 
<img id="documentSelect_enterwait" src="/devstaging/img/ajax_process.gif" style="display: none" border="0" />
<div id="documentSelect_enteroptions" class="autocompleter"></div>

<script>

    Event.observe($('documentSelect_enter'), 'keypress', function(event){ if(event.keyCode == Event.KEY_ENTER) return false; }, true);

    function documentSelect_updateElement(li){
        var id = li.readAttribute('id');
        if (id != 'noresults'){
            $('theForm:documentSelect_picker').value = id;
            $('theForm:documentSelect_add').click();
            $('documentSelect_enter').value = '';
            return false;
        }
    }
    function documentSelect_actionButton(){
        if(false){
            $('theForm:documentSelect_addAction').click();
        }

    }
    document.documentSelect_multiPicker =  new Ajax.Autocompleter('documentSelect_enter', 'documentSelect_enteroptions', "/devstaging/multiPickerResults?p=name&t=Document&subsetOf=&label=label", {paramName: "q", updateElement: documentSelect_updateElement, indicator: "documentSelect_enterwait"});
</script><input id="theForm:documentSelect_add" name="theForm:documentSelect_add" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','theForm',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){documentSelect_actionButton();},'parameters':{'theForm:documentSelect_add':'theForm:documentSelect_add'} ,'actionUrl':'/devstaging/pca/batch/add'} );return false;" style="display: none" type="button" /><input id="theForm:documentSelect_addAction" name="theForm:documentSelect_addAction" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('_viewRoot','theForm',event,{'parameters':{'theForm:documentSelect_addAction':'theForm:documentSelect_addAction'} ,'actionUrl':'/devstaging/pca/batch/add'} );return false;" style="display: none" type="button" /><input id="theForm:documentSelect_picker" type="hidden" name="theForm:documentSelect_picker" /><span id="theForm:documentSelect_zone"><span id="theForm:documentSelect_noselections">
```

it returns a list of 4 items, from which I should select the top one. But I can't click on that top item with Selenium WebDriver. I use FireBug and it doesn't give me any hooks for it. When I try to hover over it with firebug "inspect", the list disappears or doesn't return any "hooks" (xpath, id, css etc). How do I make the WebDriver to select it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `By.XPath("//input[@id=\"documentSelect_enter\"]")`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "returns AJAX list of 4 items".  I may not be understanding your question correctly.

Comment: You know like in google when you start typing a word, it lists your the suggestions below. So same way here, when I type that keyword, it returns "suggestions" the same way the google search does. That's what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your answer and understand now...  You could speak to your developer and see what the html looks like.  You could probably also run your automation up to the point where the 4 items appear and then print out the dom using selenium like this: String html = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");

Comment: I get the following error: INFO: Executing: [2a5f47e5-a686-c046-9b79-837a8e0a94c1, executeScript {"script":"document.getElementsByTagNam\u200c\u200be('html')[0].innerHTML","args":[]}]
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: hello, Sam? i've edited original post to show the full html. I think that's what you wanted to see.

Comment: The source of the page is different than the DOM which is constantly updated and contains only the html (and not script). I'm still unsure what HTML is generated by the script on your page, and that's what you need to see in order to find a way to identify it for selenium...  I'm not sure what that error is about, you might look it up to figure out how to get past it.

Comment: Sam, but that's basically is the question of this thread. And your answer for me is to talk to developers...

Comment: No... The answer is to run your automation up to the point where those 4 json items pop up and then run the javascript I provided so that you can see the html and from that, determine how to identify the element.  An alternate approach would be to talk to a developer of the page who should also be able to tell you what the html will be.  I just tested the code that I provided and found one error.  You should return the value, so the javascript should be "return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML".  I don't get an exception executing that javascript.

Comment: ohh I see... I didn't know that whatever the output of the AJAX process, it is always going to produce *html* and every time it would produce a different html. It is a valuable information. I am going on holidays for 1 week, and will be able to give it a try only when I return. Happy New Year and hope to talk to you in a week, Sam.

Comment: Gents, if you need to continue this thread, please consider moving it to an SQA chat room.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this problem with auto-suggested text box and I saw deeply at the code at the downline you would be seen anchor tag either with `ul` or `li`. Try to see the values whatever you are put in the text box at those anchor tags. Once you would be able to see that you can easily get the suggested values from that ajax text box.